# CRM 2011 Solution Import Error - 80044190 - Invalid Plugin Type

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

So, we have the following environments

1. Development
2. Test
3. SIT
4. UAT
5. Live

In the Development environment, I have a solution called Base Solution which has the following components

1. Plugin Assembly called MyCompany.Dynamics.CRM.ContactHandler
2. SDK Message MyCompany.Dynamics.CRM.ContactHandler.OnChangeOfStatus
3. SDK Message MyCompany.Dynamics.CRM.ContactHandler.OnChangeOfDateOfBirth

Now, this solution has been deployed to Test / SIT / UAT and Live and it is working fine.

I add a new SDK Message (MyCompany.Dynamics.CRM.ContactHandler.OnChangeOfContactType) to the same assembly on my development environment. I do this via the CRM 2011 Developer Toolkit for VS2010 and deploy the Plugin to the default solution.

I then create a new solution in the Development organisation called CR001Solution and add the plugin assembly and the newly added SDK Message (MyCompany.Dynamics.CRM.ContactHandler.OnChangeOfContactType). So, the new solution CR001Solution (version 1.0.0.0) has just the plugin assembly and the newly added SDK message.

I export this solution as unmanaged and deploy it to Test. It works fine. I then do a round of testing, find some bugs and then fix it in the Development organisation. I then increment the version of CR001Solution (1.0.0.1) and then deploy it to Test. This works fine as well.

When I attempt to deploy this solution to SIT (i.e., version 1.0.0.1 of CR001Solution), I get the following error.

> Unable to load plugin type with an error code of 80044190

I was able to fix this as follows based on the [link](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0c4b02b-d5ff-45cc-9467-43dd211b206d/error-message-unable-to-load-plugin-type?forum=crm)

1. Import just the plugin assembly without the new plugin steps, and
   publish. The plugin assembly is now updated with the new plugin
   class definition.
2. Add the new plugin steps and import the
   solution again. The solution should now be imported successfully.

I quite do not understand why this is the case.

From the link above,

> I believe the bug is CRM Solution Import routine checks for the plugin
>   class/type definition in the existing plugin assembly in the server
>   rather than the new plugin assembly in the solution being imported

What I do not understand is the following

1. When I deployed 1.0.0.0 of CR001Solution to Test, should it not have failed with the same reason, i.e., `Solution Import routing checks for the plugin class / type definition in the existing plugin assembly in the server rather than the new plugin assembly in the solution being imported`?
2. Why does it work when I deploy the changes to Test but fails when I attempt to do so in SIT?

Any insights will be most helpful.

Note: All solutions are unmanaged solutions.